# Is there a free python library for phone calling?

Tags: python, phone-call

I'm writting a small python script notify me when certain condition met. I used smtplib which does the emailing for me, but I also want the script to call my cell phone as well.

I can't find a free library for phone callings. Does anyone know any?

Answer (score 8):

Make the calls using Skype, and use the [`Skype4Py`](https://developer.skype.com/wiki/Skype4Py) API.

If you want other suggestions, please specify how you want to make the call (modem? Some software bridge? What?).

Also, might I suggest that you send an SMS instead of placing a call? You can do that via Skype too, btw.

Comment: Python is the best evar! It has libraries to hand phone calling! Amazing! :D

Answer (score 4):

[Twilio](http://www.twilio.com/) can make calls through their API.  Pay as you go.  Worked well for wakeup calls for me.

Answer (score 1):

I've used Skype4Py very successfully. Keep in mind though it does require Skype to be installed and costs the standard rate for SkypeOut.